# prepareForSegue : Using Blocks on Objective C

Tags: objective-c-blocks

When the code below gets run (once it enters the method), there is a few seconds of freeze. I can't even scroll up or down. I am trying to remove that by using block but even with the code below it still freezes. Here is the code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueu= dispatch_queue_create("downloader",NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueu, ^{
    NSDictionary *placeDictionary =
    [self.topPlaces objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [[segue destinationViewController] setPhotoList:[FlickrFetcher photosInPlace:placeDictionary
                                                                         maxResults:50]
                                             withTitle:[[sender textLabel] text]];
    });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create your dispatch queue *once*, rather than on every call to this method.  Also note that you can't use `indexPathForSelectedRow` from a background thread (i.e. your block); you need to take that and store it in a variable in your method, *outside* of your block.  You may also have trouble with `[topPlaces objectAtIndex:]`, unless you take care about thread safety.